# Scaling in CanvasJS

Tags: canvasjs

I am using CanvasJS in my site to show statistics of physical items (all data points are integers). Is there a way to customize the scaling of the chart so that when only a single data point is shown, the yAxis scaling does not show decimals.

I have also noticed, with plotting a single item at (x = 0, y = 1), the XAxis decides to plot the point in the middle with a tick mark on either side showing -1 and 1. Since this is statistics of an inventory (physical items). I would like to be able to see a single point with integer Y-axis labels.

Any support would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can force axisY to use integers by setting it's [interval](http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisy/interval/) to 1, 2, 5, 10 etc.

And in order to avoid -1 & 1, you can start using label property of dataPoint instead of x. Here is [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/QwZuf/226/).

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

data: [{
    type: "column",
    dataPoints: [{
        label: "0",
        y: 1
    }, ]
}],
axisY: {
    interval: 1
}    
});

chart.render();
```